# Can I prevent viewport manipulation though the right mouse button in X3DOM?

Tags: javascript, viewport, x3dom

I am using the right mouse button for custom user interaction - even when in "view" mode - with x3d.runtime.turnTable() enabled.

Can I prevent x3d from reacting to the right mouse button completely?

Zooming is still ok using the mouse wheel, and the left mouse button to rotate - so there's nothing really missing.